# Write data to a specific column with a randomly generated username using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a script using openpyxl that can automatically fill a specific column in an excel file with randomly generated usernames. This is my code at the moment:

```
import random
import openpyxl

path = "E:\\Desktop\\"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('names.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

def random_names():
    for x in range (0, 9):
        color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
        animal = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
        number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

        randomColor = random.randrange(0, len(color))
        randomAnimal = random.randrange(0, len(animal))
        randomNumber = random.randrange(0, len(number))

        name = "Username: " + color[randomColor] + animal[randomAnimal] + number[randomNumber]

list = [random_names()]

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=5, max_row=2):
    for cell in row:
        sheet.append(list)

wb.save('usernames.xlsx')
```

[Example of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wert5.png)

I'm not sure if iter_rows should be used here. I tried using a range of cells like ws['C1':'C8'] but that didn't work. Basically I want to fill the cell C1 to C8 with random usernames using the random_names function.

Help would be greatly appreciated! (sorry if I'm slow at answering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your function isn't returning anything. Try it like that:

```
def random_names():
    names = list()
    for x in range (0, 9):
        color = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black", "Yellow", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink"]
        animal = ["Cat", "Dog", "Snake", "Mouse", "Tiger", "Leopard", "Moose", "Wolf", "Bear"]
        number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]

        randomColor = random.randrange(0, len(color))
        randomAnimal = random.randrange(0, len(animal))
        randomNumber = random.randrange(0, len(number))

        name = "Username: " + color[randomColor] + animal[randomAnimal] + number[randomNumber]
        names.append(name)
    return names    

list = random_names()
```